# Confused about a part of the proof for $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ is Banach provided that $V$ is normed and $W$ is Banach.

Tags: analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ be the set of linear maps where $V$ is normed and $W$ is Banach. In Analysis Now, Pedersen states that $\{T_n\} \subset \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is Cauchy, then $\{T_n(x)\} \subset W$ is Cauchy in $W$. Even though this makes intuitive sense, I was trying to show this. Note, I am using the operator norm. Chatgbt says that this is true $$||(T_n-T_m)x|| \leq ||T_n - T_m||||x||$$ note that I am taking different norms, but I can't seem to prove it. Sorry if this is obvious like Pedersen presents it, and my linear algebra is definitely rusty.

Comment: This is true by definition of operator norm

Comment: I thought the operator norm is defined as $\sup \{||T(x)||:x \in V, ||x|| \leq 1 \}$. However $x \in V$, this might not be true $||x|| \leq 1$

Comment: Let $x$ be nonzero. $$\|Tx\|_W=\|T(x/\|x\|_V)\cdot\|x\|_V\|_W=\|T(x/\|x\|_V)\|_W\cdot\|x\|_V\le\|T\|\cdot\|x\|_V$$

Comment: oh I see, I am dumb lol. I just realized I used a similar argument to prove that the operator norm is a norm .

Comment: "Chatgbt says that this is true" -- ChatGPT cannot be relied on to say much of anything, and can be convinced that $2+2=5$ if nudged right. It is glorified text prediction, incapable of genuine new thought, and unreliable for serious mathematics.

Comment: do not use chat gpt for proof verification. At present MSE is vastly superior for this purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, $$\Vert T \Vert = \sup\{\Vert Tx \Vert : x \in X, \Vert x \Vert \leq 1\}.$$
For any non-zero $x \in X$, using the homogeneity of $T$ we get $$\Vert Tx \Vert = \left\Vert \Vert x \Vert T\left(\frac{1}{\Vert x \Vert}x\right)\right\Vert \leq \Vert x\Vert \Vert T \Vert = \Vert T \Vert \Vert x \Vert.$$

Now apply this in your case with $T = T_n - T_m$.